# dpkg was interrupted

Tags: linux, dpkg

I was trying to install a program via terminal. But suddenly my computer was shut down because electricity was going off.  Later while I was trying to install any program using terminal, it gave me this error:

```
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

Now what should I do to fix it and install correctly?

Comment: Maybe you should read what the computer is trying to tell you... Some programmer created `dpkg` with passion, created error messages just to people ignore them?

Comment: You're absolutely right. I'm sorry for my mistake

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems to some packages didn't configured correctly.
To fix it:

```
$sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

If it doesn't work try this:

```
$sudo apt-get install -f
```

then again

```
$sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

I think, when you search this problem on Google, you can find a lot of solutions that well-explained.

Answer (score 6):

Just do what it's telling you to:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```